# HDInsight cluster with metastore using powershell error

Tags: powershell, azure-hdinsight, hive-metastore

I am trying to create HDInsight cluster in Azure with Metastore using the Powershell script. But it is throwing BadRequest: RegionCapabilityNotAvailable,Region capability not available for region 'East US' error. But East US is a supported region for the HDInsight cluster. Please find my code below.

```
$storageAccountResourceGroupName = "hdi-rg"
$storageAccountName = "qwertyhdi"
#$storageAccountKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $storageAccountResourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName)[0].value
$storageContainer = "qwertyiopasdf-2020-05-03t08-30-23-118z"

# Cluster configuration info
$location = "East US"
$clusterResourceGroupName = "hdi-rg"
$clusterName = "qwertyiopasdf"
$username = "admin"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$clusterCreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList ($username, $password)

# Hive metastore info
$hiveSqlServer = "server"
$hiveDb = "db123"
$sqlusername = "qwerty"
$sqlpassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$hiveCreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList ($sqlusername, $sqlpassword)

New-AzStorageAccount `
    -ResourceGroupName $storageAccountResourceGroupName `
    -Name $storageAccountName `
    -Location $location `
    -SkuName Standard_LRS `
    -Kind StorageV2 `
    -EnableHttpsTrafficOnly 1

# Note: Storage account kind BlobStorage cannot be used as primary storage.

$storageAccountKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey `
                                -ResourceGroupName $storageAccountResourceGroupName `
                                -Name $storageAccountName)[0].Value

$defaultStorageContext = New-AzStorageContext `
                                -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName `
                                -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey

New-AzStorageContainer `
    -Name $storageContainer `
    -Context $defaultStorageContext #use the cluster name as the container name


$metastore = New-AzHDInsightClusterConfig | Add-AzHDInsightMetastore -SqlAzureServerName "$hiveSqlServer.database.windows.net" -DatabaseName $hiveDb -Credential $hiveCreds -MetastoreType HiveMetastore


New-AzHDInsightCluster -Location $location -ResourceGroupName $clusterResourceGroupName -ClusterName $clusterName -ClusterType Hadoop -OSType Windows -ClusterSizeInNodes 1 -HttpCredential $clusterCreds -DefaultStorageAccountName "$storageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net" -DefaultStorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey -DefaultStorageContainer $storageContainer -Config $metastore
```

Comment: Hi Anbu, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is -OSType Windows still valid. I realize "Windows" is listed as an option from the PowerShell specs, but I think "linux" is the only value that will actually work.

Comment: Yes, it was not valid and used Linux. Now it worked thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will receive this error message `BadRequest: RegionCapabilityNotAvailable,Region capability not available for region 'East US'`, when underlying compute sku is not available for the selected region in that subscription.

I would request you to check if the resource are available from Azure Portal.

Azure Portal => Select your subscription => Usage + Quotas

Filter with => Microsoft.Compute and Region => East US

[image]

If you're unable to find a suitable SKU in that region/zone or an alternative region/zone that meets your business needs, submit a [SKU request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/sku-series-unavailable) or [Quota increase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/regional-quota-requests) to Azure Support.

Comment: Hi, sorry the Quotas and region were correct but the OS type was not valid. It supported only Linux. Anyway thanks for the help

Comment: Glad to know it helped. Do click on accept it as answer and up-vote for the same.